# What is this "Style" called ? And How do i use it?

Tags: questions, present-tense

Example :

- Hahaha, I was just joking ...[stops], or was I ?
- He Sounds very familiar, or does he ?

Sorry for the bad explanation but I think you got the point here ...

Comment: What part? Do you mean the part after the last comma ("or does he?")?

Comment: Explicitly correcting yourself within a sentence is called [metanoia](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/2567/explicitly-correcting-yourself-while-writing-how-appropriate-is-it/2570#2570).

Comment: These are examples of tag questions (statements that end with a short question). The first example is a *sarcastic* tag question.

Comment: Welcome! I think the suggestion of *metanoia* gets you the term you're looking for, and that was covered in the duplicate question. The "how do I use it" part needs clarification to be answered. Do you have concerns about punctuation? word choice? Please look at the proposed duplicate, and if it doesn't solve things, edit this question to explain more.